# Retrieving values from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am working on a school project and I'm stuck.

The requirement is to write a single query that gathers data from nine different tables and returns a result.

It needs the client names, contract names, project names, employees that logged hours for April, total hours logged by employee, employee rate, charges per employee for the projects, and the contact names for each contract.
(I know, that's a lot of data to pull.)

The tables are:

```
 Clients   
-------------------------------
ClientID | CommonName  

 ContractTypes   
--------------------------------------  
ContractTypeID | ContractType   

 Contracts   
---------------------------------------------------------  
ContractID | ClientID (FK) | ContractType (FK)   

 Projects   
---------------------------------------------------  
ProjectID | ProjectName | ContractID (FK)   

 Contacts   
-----------------------------------------  
ContactID | FirstName | LastName  

 ContractContacts   
--------------------------------------------------  
ContractID (PK/FK) | ContactID (PK/FK)   

 Employees   
-----------------------------------  
EmpID | name | titleID | level   

 BillingRates   
----------------------  
titleID | level | rate  

 WorkHours   
----------------------------  
EmpID | HoursWorked
```

I ran the following, but it resulted is over 23,000 rows - not what is needed:

```
select 
   clients.CommonName, projects.ProjectName, employees.FirstName,  
   employees.lastname, sum(workhours.hoursworked) as TotalHours,  
   BillingRates.Rate,contacts.FirstName, contacts.LastName,     
   contacts.AddrLine1, contacts.AddrLine2, contacts.City, 
   contacts.State_Province, contacts.Zip
from 
   employees, BillingRates, Clients, Projects, WorkHours, Contracts, Contacts
group by 
   clients.CommonName, projects.ProjectName, employees.FirstName,  
   employees.lastname, BillingRates.Rate, contacts.FirstName, 
   contacts.LastName, contacts.AddrLine1, contacts.AddrLine2, 
   contacts.City, contacts.State_Province, contacts.Zip
```

I honestly have no idea how to pull in all that data into one query to generate one report.

I received help on generating a query to return the employees that logged hours for April, total hours logged by the employee, and the charges per employee for the projects in the following:

```
select 
   employees.EmpID, 
   sum(workhours.hoursworked) as 'TotalHours',
   firstname, lastname, 
   ISNULL(sum(workhours.hoursworked), 0) * ISNULL(min(rate), 0) AS 'TotalRate'
from 
   employees 
inner join 
   workhours on employees.empid = WorkHours.EmpID
left join  
   BillingRates on employees.titleid = billingrates.titleid
                and employees.level = billingrates.level
where 
   WH_Month = 4
group by 
   LastName, firstname, employees.EmpID
```

I assume this query would be nested into the outer query, but I don't know how to construct it.

Would someone be able to assist with writing this query?

Comment: The first query needs joins. Please look up on `INNER JOINS` in books online

Comment: If you are supposed to do it in a single query, then don't use nested queries. If all you need, is all of the columns, then joining on all of the tables will get you that. You would then select what columns you need from the joined tables

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many joins as you need;

```
from
    contracts
    inner join contractcontacts on contracts.contractID = contractcontacts.contractID
    inner join contracttypes on contracts.contracttype = contracttypes.contracttype
    inner join contacts on contactcontacts.contactID = contacts.contactID
    inner join clients on contracts.clientID = clients.clientID
    ...
```

Just add all tables with the distinct relation they have. And check if it needs to be left outer join instead of inner join for example, meaning the right-side table might not have any rows and you would like those to appear as NULL instead of suppressing whole row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner joins but I don't see FK for all the tables to join with another table.
from 
   employees 
   inner join BillingRates on ???
   inner join clients cls on ???
   inner join Contracts cs on cls.clientid = cs.clientid
   inner join Projects ps on ,ps.contractid = cs.contractid
   inner join WorkHours ws on e.empid  = ws.empid`enter code here`
   inner join ContractContacts cscs on cs.contractid = cscs.contractid
   inner join Contacts c  on c.contact_id = cscs.contactid

How would you join Employees  to billing rates and clients that my questions is.. If you know the answer than you can use above joins to solve your problem

Comment: Most of the tables do have FK, I just didn't add them all. Sorry.  What code are you referring when you say "enter code here"?

Comment: Hey ted,
Sorry for late reply.. There was some format issue so I guess "enter code here" appended itself in my code when I pasted my query here as an answer. You can ignore that and replace "???" with table1.fk = table2.pk and use the query.

Comment: You can use the same way as you have tried to get sum and multiplied values with long query just use alias name of that table before all the fields name so that no conflict will be there even if the names are same in multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the help.

I was able to come up with the following query:

```
select clients.CommonName, projects.ProjectName, employees.FirstName,  
   employees.lastname, sum(workhours.hoursworked) as TotalHours,  
   BillingRates.Rate,contacts.FirstName, contacts.LastName,     
   contacts.AddrLine1, contacts.AddrLine2, contacts.City, 
   contacts.State_Province, contacts.Zip
   ISNULL(sum(workhours.hoursworked), 0) * ISNULL(min(rate), 0) AS TotalRate  
from Contracts   
    inner join ContractsContacts on contracts.ContractID =         ContractsContacts.contractid  
    inner join contracttypes on contracts.ContractTypeID =         contracttypes.ContractTypeID  
    inner join contacts on ContractsContacts.ContactID = contacts.ContactID
inner join projects on contracts.ContractID = projects.ContractID
inner join Clients on contracts.ClientID = clients.ClientID
inner join WorkHours on WorkHours.ProjectID = projects.ProjectID
inner join Employees on WorkHours.EmpID = Employees.EmpID
left join BillingRates on Employees.TitleID = BillingRates.TitleID and
Employees.Level = BillingRates.Level  
where workhours.WH_Month = 4  
order by Clients.CommonName, Projects.ProjectName, Employees.LastName
```

But I cannot figure out how to sum the total hours worked per employee for April and the multiply that times the rate into the query. I used the following query to obtain that information, but I do not know how to add it to the longer query:

```
select 
   employees.EmpID, 
   sum(workhours.hoursworked) as 'TotalHours',
   firstname, lastname, 
   ISNULL(sum(workhours.hoursworked), 0) * ISNULL(min(rate), 0) AS 'TotalRate'
from 
   employees 
inner join 
   workhours on employees.empid = WorkHours.EmpID
left join  
   BillingRates on employees.titleid = billingrates.titleid
            and employees.level = billingrates.level
where 
   WH_Month = 4
group by 
   LastName, firstname, employees.EmpID
```

I would appreciate help on this.